# Закладываю в set 7 гарантированно различных элементов, а получаю только 6

Tags: c++, c++11, множества

Имею структуру `pair<int, pair<int, int>>`, через typedef обозванную как guard.
Имею `set<guard, comp>`, с компаратором, который сравнивает только по second.first.

Добавляю несколько `guard` в этот `set`. `second.first` могут повторяться (!), но `first` и `second.second` всегда строго различны. Не смотря на это, `set` куда-то "съедает" один элемент. Именно тот, у которого `second.first` повторяет оный у другого элемента. Полагаю, дело в компараторе.

Вот входные данные и наши некорректные выходные. Видно, что вводится 7 элементов, а в set остаётся только 6.

IN:

```
7 1
2 3 4 5 7 8 9
0 3 7 9 5 8 9
```

OUT:

```
9 9 6
8 8 5
7 5 4
5 9 3
4 7 2
3 3 1
2 0 0
!6
```

Вот код:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define endl "\n"
#define pb push_back
#define ff first
#define ss second

const double pi = 3.14159265358979323;
const double eps = 0.0000001;

typedef pair<int, pair<int, int>> guard;
#define money ss.ff
#define strength ff
#define num ss.ss

struct comp {
    bool operator() (guard a, guard b) const {
        return a.money > b.money;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    cout.tie(nullptr);
#ifdef LOCAL
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
#else
    //freopen("palin.in", "r", stdin);
    //freopen("palin.out", "w", stdout);
#endif

    int n, k;
    vector<guard> a;
    set<guard, comp> q;
    vector<int> m;

    cin >> n >> k;
    a.resize(n);
    m.assign(n, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        a[i].num = i;
        a[i].strength = x;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        a[i].money = x;
        m[i] = x;
    }

    for(auto &x : a) {
        q.insert(x);
    }

    sort(a.rbegin(), a.rend());

    for(auto &x : a) cout << x.strength << " " << x.money << " " << x.num << endl;
    cout << "!" << q.size() << endl;

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ну так у вас получается из 7 элементов только 6 уникальных.

Comment: `std::set::insert` возвращает пару iterator, bool, где iterator указывает на вставленный элемент или элемент, помешавший вставке, а bool == true если элемент был вставлен, а иначе false

Comment: @vegorov Ну так у каждого поля num гарантированно уникальное значение. И strength по условиям задачи строго различны. Повторяться могут только money.

Comment: Ага, и ваш компаратор именно money и сравнивает, не правда ли ?

Comment: `std::set` - это сбалансированное бинарное дерево поиска, и для его работы требуется поддержка оператора сравнения `>` или `функтора`, выполняющего эту операцию сравнения. Отдавая в `std::set` оператор `>` или функтор, вы как бы заодно отдаёте туда и оператор сравнения, ведь если a > b и b > a вернул false - значит a==b, и вставка уже не пройдёт

Comment: Так как вам уже ответили, удовлетворите мое любопытсятво: для чего все эти дефайны в начале?   Вы же  специально делаете код менее читабельным...

Comment: @vegorov а это можно как-то по-простому исправить, не выстраивая огромные конструкции из if?

Comment: @Hovsepyan конечно знаю, что define это дурной тон, но так как задача передо мной стоит сугубо олимпиадная, мне нужно как можно быстрее написать решение. Потому и пользуюсь такими решениями, чтобы, например, не писать лишний компаратор (Для sort) :)

Comment: Вы закладываете в `set`, который использует компаратаор по `money`, семь элементов, два элемента из которых имеют значение `money`, равное 9. В set накапливаются шесть элементов - это корректный результат. В чем вопрос - непонятно.

Comment: @Hovsepyan Ой, вы другие имели в виду. Они тоже сугубо олимпиадные. endl для оптимизации, остальное для скорости записи кода. Это на самом деле далеко не всё. Там на самом деле сейчас огромная шапка из pragma, define, typedef и const на все случаи жизни.

Comment: @VVT моя вопрос заключался непониманании мной того, как set проверяет элементы на уникальность.)

Comment: использовать pb вместо push_back или  endl  вместо "\n" влияет на  быстрое решение и на компаратор?  И  ко всему тому, что написав лишные строчки и  стараясь запутать и сам себя и  читателям своего кода, вы хотите решить быстрее и еще говорите, что эта тривиальная задача является олимпиадной - все это меня еще больше удивляет.  Не воспринимайте это как упрек, но лучше  быть попроще в  написании кодов

Comment: @AR_Hovsepyan это (Видимо не вполне) минимальный код для проявления ошибки. Сама задача конечно не заключается в добавлении элементов в set)

Comment: @Егор Левоненко, представлением  set   является дерево, в который можете вставить обьекты только с различным  значением. Если значение совпадают, то вставка игнорируется. Если у вас другие намерения, то используйте    multiset

Comment: @AR_Hovsepyan Да, из за моего мерзкого компаратора multiset тоже работал не так, как хотелось.) Буду править, спасибо за информацию.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan по поводу define - это стандартная практика среди олимпиадников. Основная причина - ограниченное количество времени при участии в олимпиадах. Участники, так делающие, делают так постоянно, и им это не мешает. Кроме них этот код (в некоторых видах соревнований) могут видеть другие участники, которые могут проанализировать решение, и придумать тест, валящий решение исходного участника. Таким образом,запутывание кода с помощью define даже может помочь.

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко в `с++11` появились `std::tuple`, которые умеют сравниваться. Посмотрите документацию на `std::tuple` и `std::tie`. На cppreference стандартный [пример](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) как раз про это.

Comment: @vegorov, вот теперь понятно, спасибо большое за информацию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::set` не проверяет элементы на *уникальность*, а проверяет элементы на *эквивалентность*. Эквивалентность как раз определяется через заданный вами функтор сравнения. Если ваш функтор сравнения говорит, что вставляемый элемент *эквивалентен* какому-то уже присутствующему в контейнере, то вставки делаться не будет. А равен ли этот элемент своему эквиваленту или нет (с точки зрения буквально хранящихся в нем данных) значения не имеет.

В данном случае вы написали функтор сравнения, который говорит, что все элементы с равными значениями в полях `second.first` эквивалентны. Это и обусловило наблюдаемое вами поведение.